# JTable two-dimensional object array

Tags: java, jtable

May this question is repeated but I tried most of the solution but none of them fit in my problem.
Referring to this page : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

I want to create the JTable to read from objects from my custom class.As an initial step, I want to test the looping with the JTable. As follow:

```
Object[][] tripsData =new Object[3][6];
for(int j=0; j< 3;j++)
        for(int i =0; i< 6;i++)
        {   tripsData[j][i]= new Object[] {"Kathy", "Smith","wait",  "Snowboarding", 5, "false"};
        }
```

The code works fine except the output it shows like this:

```
 [Ljava.lang.Object;@41488024
 [Ljava.lang.Object;@54c83ae1
 [Ljava.lang.Object;@161a4f2c
```

I tried to use, toString() and valueOf(), but the same thing.
Any suggestion to solve

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.Object;@41488024` is the `toString` method of `Object[]`

Comment: @NengLiu so, how can I show the original text ?. I'm forced to use Object instead of String to put it in the JTable.

Comment: What's the expect result? Please edit the question.

Comment: And, do you really want to make `tripsData` an array? It is a single element in the matrix!

Comment: @NengLiu no it's not a single element. It contain dynamic data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are creating a three-dimensional array instead of the 2D that you need. In your code, you use

```
tripsData[j][i]= new Object[] {"Kathy", "Smith","wait",  "Snowboarding", 5, "false"};
```

thus `"Kathy"` in the resulting `Object` has an index `[j][i][0]`, `"Smith"` has an index `[j][i][1]` and so on. Populate your array like so:

```
Object[][] tripsData =new Object[3][6];
        for(int j=0; j< 3;j++) {
            tripsData[j] = new Object[]{"Kathy", "Smith", "wait", "Snowboarding", 5, "false"};
        }
```

Then both this

```
    for (Object[] row : tripsData) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(row[j]);
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

and this

```
for (Object[] row : tripsData) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

will work fine

Comment: THNAK YOU very much, yes you are right. As I put the whole columns in the object I shouldn't use it as a single cell.

Comment: Happy to help =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.toString()`, somewhat similar to this snippet:

```
    Object[][] arr = new Object[2][2];
    arr[0][0] = "00";
    arr[0][1] = "01";
    arr[1][0] = "10";
    arr[1][1] = "11";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[0]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[1]));
```

This will print

```
[00, 01]
[10, 11]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it doesn't work with me.

Comment: It doesn't work in what way? What output you see when you write ```System.out.println(tripsData[0]);``` after your example? Show us some code you tried, otherwise it's very difficult to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your support, It was solved by the next comment by evnica.